# HQL Update issue

Tags: hibernate, hql, nhibernate-inheritance

I have two entities. Data_mart and entity_data. entity_data extends data_mart. 
I have id column in both the data_mart and entity_data. data_id in entity mart is the foregin key of the data_mart(Pkey over there is id).

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "data_mart")
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type")
public class DataMaster {

/** The id. */
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = IDENTITY)
@Column(unique = true, nullable = false)
private Long id;
/** The type. */
private String type;

/** The created by. */
private String createdBy;
.....
 }

@Entity
@Table(name = "entity_data")
@PrimaryKeyJoinColumn(name = "dataId")
@DiscriminatorValue("FILE")
@Where(clause = "active = '1'")
public class EntityData extends DataMaster {

/** The data id. */
 @Column(insertable = false, updatable = false)
    private Long dataId;

/** The delimiter. */
private String delimiter;
....
 }
```

And the table structure of the child table is as follows

```
CREATE TABLE entity_data (
id bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
data_id bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
delimiter varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
file_path `varchar(200) DEFAULT NULL,
...
)
```

When i try to update the table entity_data with an HQL query, below is the intermediate query formed by the Hibernate

```
create temporary table if not exists HT_entity_data (id bigint not null);
insert into HT_entity_data
select entitydata0_.data_id as data_id from entity_data 
entitydata0_ inner join data_master entitydata0_1_ on   
 entitydata0_.data_id=entitydata0_1_.id where entitydata0_.file_path='abcdd'


 update entity_data set file_path='new_path' 
 where (id) IN  (select data_id from HT_entity_data)
```

The above query is giving wrong results. in the where clause of the above update statement, id is coming. It should have been data_id.

I could not figure out how this is taken??

Answer (score 0):

You must **not** have an ID in the subclass. It extends the base class, which already has an ID. In the `JOINED` inheritance strategy, the primary key of the table associated with the subclass is also a foreign key to the primary key of the table associated with the base class.

See [the dcumentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#mapping-declaration-joinedsubclass).

Comment: As you could see, base class don't have the id column. But the corresponding table has the column in the name id.